# Class; Struct; Enum confusion, what is better?

Tags: c#, class, return-value, message

I have 46 rows of information, 2 columns each row ("Code Number", "Description"). These codes are returned to the client dependent upon the success or failure of their initial submission request. I do not want to use a database file (csv, sqlite, etc) for the storage/access.  The closest type that I can think of for how I want these codes to be shown to the client is the exception class.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but from what I can tell enums do not allow strings, though this sort of structure seemed the better option initially based on how it works (e.g. 100 = "missing name in request").

Thinking about it, creating a class might be the best modus operandi.  However I would appreciate more experienced advice or direction and input from those who might have been in a similar situation.

Currently this is what I have:

```
    class ReturnCode
{
    private int _code;
    private string _message;

    public ReturnCode(int code)
    {
        Code = code;
    }

    public int Code
    {
        get
        {
            return _code;
        }
        set
        {
            _code = value;
            _message = RetrieveMessage(value);
        }
    }

    public string Message { get { return _message; } }

    private string RetrieveMessage(int value)
    {
        string message;

        switch (value)
        {
            case 100:
                message = "Request completed successfuly";
                break;
            case 201:
                message = "Missing name in request.";
                break;
            default:
                message = "Unexpected failure, please email for support";
                break;
        }

        return message;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best would be both a class and an enumeration. Then you can have more descriptive identifiers than "201".

A structure would also work, but they are harder to implement correctly, so you should stick to a class unless you specifically need a structure for some reason.

You don't need to store a reference to the message in the class, you can get that when needed in the `Message` property. A `switch` is implemented using a hash table (if there are five values or more), so the lookup is very fast.

```
public enum ReturnIdentifier {
  Success = 100,
  MissingName = 201;
}

public class ReturnCode {

  public ReturnIdentifier Code { get; private set; }

  public ReturnCode(ReturnIdentifier code) {
    Code = code;
  }

  public string Message {
    get {
      switch (Code) {
        case ReturnIdentifier.Success:
          return "Request completed successfuly.";
        case ReturnIdentifier.MissingName:
          return "Missing name in request.";
        default:
          return "Unexpected failure, please email for support.";
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Usage:

```
ReturnCode code = new ReturnCode(ReturnIdentifier.Success);
```

If you get an integer code from somewhere, you can still use it as the enumerator values correspond to the codes:

```
int error = 201;
ReturnCode code = new ReturnCode((ReturnIdentifier)error);
```

(If the integer code doesn't correspond to any of the identifiers in the enumeration, it's still perfectly valid to do the conversion. When getting the `Message` value, it will end up in the `default` case as the value doesn't match any of the other cases.)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. You where clear in your reasoning and provided straightforward examples. I could not have asked for a better response. Thank you immensely for the help.

Answer (score 3):

I think choosing a class(as you did) is a good decision. You can make the code a little more compact and readable, if you use `Dictionary<int, string>` for mapping codes to descriptions.

```
_dict.Add(100, "Description1");
_dict.Add(201, "Description2");
...............................
```

And `RetrieveMessage`:

```
return _dict[value];
```

Answer (score 0):

How about deriving from Dictionary, or storing the data table in code using a Dictionary field that you can index into?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a dictionary based approach would look more elegant.

```
    private static Dictionary<int, string> errorCodes = 
    new Dictionary<int, string>()
    {
        {100, "Request completed successfuly"},
        {200, "Missing name in request."}
    };

    private string RetrieveMessage(int value)
    {
        string message;
        if (!errorCodes.TryGetValue(value, out message))
            message = "Unexpected failure, please email for support";

        return message;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely be more slower (since it uses Reflection) but speaking of being compact, I think [Enums With Custom Attributes](http://blogs.msdn.com/abhinaba/archive/2005/10/20/c-enum-and-overriding-tostring-on-it.aspx) is appropriate for this need. Please continue reading the comments since [DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute%28VS.71%29.aspx) is mentioned there. Something like;

```
public enum ErrorMessage
{
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("Request completed successfuly")]
    Success = 100,
    [System.ComponentModel.Description("Missing name in request.")]
    MissingName = 201
};

public static string GetDescription(this Enum en)
{
    Type type = en.GetType();

    System.Reflection.MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());

    if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
    {
        object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute),
                false);

        if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
            return ((System.ComponentModel.DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
    }  

    return en.ToString();
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ErrorMessage message = ErrorMessage.Success;
    Console.WriteLine(message.GetDescription());
}
```